# Images are not showing up in application and even on the default iis website after new install of IIs7 on Vista x64

Tags: iis-7

Seems like everything else works fine on my website but the images are not showing.  No errors are being thrown either.  Even the localhost default site image is not working.  I have the static option turned on as well.  Any ideas on how to fix this would be great.

Comment: If you browse the image (like http://theSite.com/images/image1.jpg) do you see the image? If you don't, what's the IIS error code?

Comment: I don't see the image and there is no error code.  I have freindly error messages turn off in IE 7 as well.

Comment: When you browse to the image, manually, what appears in the browser?

Answer (score 6):

You may have to turn Static Content on in World Wide Web Services / Common Http Features. This can be accessed via the 'Turn Windows Features on or off' section in the Control Panel.

See below for an example...

http://peterkellner.net/2008/04/01/iis7imageproblem/

Answer (score 0):

When I get images not appearing it is because the files themselves don't have correct permissions. Go in and make sure that the files are inheriting permissions from their parent.

Comment: The Permission are the same for the images as the parent.